# How to list only active / recently changed branches in git?

Tags: git, branch, git-branch

I sometimes work with source code repositories containing many branches, most of which are old and usually no longer relevant.

In these cases, the full list of branches from `git branch` is not very helpful. Is there a way to only list "active" branches? For example, only branches that received commits in the last *n* days? Ideally, the list would include the last commit date for each branch, and indicate if the branch is already fully merged.

P.S.: 
I realize that this can also be solved by deleting "old" branches (as discussed e.g. in [What to do with experimental non-merged git branches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988240/what-to-do-with-experimental-non-merged-git-branches) ), but this may not always be practical or accepted on a given project.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get a list of git branches, ordered by most recent commit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5188320/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-git-branches-ordered-by-most-recent-commit)

Comment: Just realized this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can use [git-for-each-ref](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-for-each-ref.html) to get a list of all the local and tracking branches sorted in descending order by the committer date of the last commit like this:

```
git for-each-ref --sort=-committerdate --format='%(committerdate:short) %(refname)' refs/heads refs/remotes
```

This outputs eg.:

```
2012-06-23 refs/heads/master
2012-06-21 refs/remotes/origin/HEAD
2012-06-21 refs/remotes/origin/master
```

You can add `--count=m` to get at most *m* branches, you can `--sort=-authordate` instead of using the committer date, you can of course use different formats. `for-each-ref` itself does not limit the result by date, this has to be scripted separately, but at least you have the dates from the commit object in hand.

Comment: Cool, *exactly* what I was looking for. It's kind of ironic that this is actually already part of git. Maybe I should read the docs...

Comment: Don't forget to run `git remote prune origin` first, else you might get an old list including things that no longer exist on the remote site

Answer (score 7):

```
ls -1 --sort=time .git/refs/heads/ | while read b; do PAGER='' git log -n1 --color --pretty=format:'%C(yellow)%d%Creset - %Cred%h%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset%n' --abbrev-commit $b --; done;
```

This oneliner prints all local branches sorted by time from newest to oldest. Each branch has last commit with human readable date string. You can add it to your `.gitconfig`.

For remote branches I came up with this creepy solution:

```
git ls-remote -h origin | while read b; do PAGER='' git log -n1 --color --pretty=format:'%ct%C(yellow)%d%Creset - %Cred%h%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset%n' --abbrev-commit $( echo $b | cut -d' ' -f1 ) --; done | sort -rn -k1,10 | cut -c11-
```

**Edit:** the more I think, the more I am afraid this could be unreliable, because `ls-remote` always connects to remote side whereas `log` not. It may require to do `fetch` before every run of this command.

Comment: Nice trick. Unfortunately, this only works for local branches, not for remote ones (under `/refs/remote`). It also does not work for local tracking branches, because the mtime of the ref file usually reflects the last fetch, not the last (upstream) commit.